# Is there any way to refresh custom view inside baseadapter after updating data?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, baseadapter

I have a custom view inside a baseadapter that is shown on listview. Currently I can update the items inside database but I cannot refresh the view. I want to refresh the view automatically after updating.Is there anyway to refresh? Please take a look at my code.

This is modle class-

```
class Item_Detail {
   var qty:Int = 0
   var id:Int = 0
   constructor()}
```

This is DatabaseHandler-

```
  val Detail: List<Item_Detail>
    get() {
        val bb=this.writableDatabase
        val seItem=ArrayList<Item_Detail>()
        val myPath=DB_PATH + REAL_DATABASE
        val db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)
        val selectQuery="Select * From Transaction_table Where date='$rowview_date' And location='$rowview_location'"
        val cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                val item=Item_Detail()
                item.id=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id2"))
                item.qty=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("quantity2"))
                seItem.add(item)
            } while(cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        db.close()
        return seItem
    }
```

This is MainActivity-

```
class Detail : AppCompatActivity() {

internal lateinit var db: DataBaseHelper
internal var seItem: List<Item_Detail> = ArrayList<Item_Detail>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

    db = DataBaseHelper(this)
    detail_date.text = rowview_date.toString()
    detail_location.text = rowview_location.toString()
    getDetail()


}
private fun getDetail() {
    seItem = db.Detail
    val adapter = Adapter_detail(this, seItem,this)
    list_detail.adapter=adapter
    list_detail.invalidate()
}}
```

This is Adapterclass-

```
  class Adapter_detail(
    internal var activity: Activity,
    internal var stitem: List<Item_Detail>,
    val context:Context

    ) : BaseAdapter() {

internal lateinit var db: DataBaseHelper
internal var inflater: LayoutInflater

init {
    inflater = activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    val rowView:View
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_row, null)
    rowView.detail_id.text = stitem[position].id.toString()
    rowView.detail_qty.text = stitem[position].qty.toString()


    rowView.btn_detail.setOnClickListener{
        db=DataBaseHelper(context)//Initiate the database
        val builder=android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        inflater=activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_layout, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        val dialog: android.app.AlertDialog=builder.create()

        var tran_edit=view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edt_edit)
        tran_edit.setText(stitem[position].qty.toString())

        dialog.show()

        var btn_edt=view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_edit)
        btn_edt.setOnClickListener {
            val item=Item(
                Integer.parseInt(stitem[position].id.toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(1.toString()),
                tran_edit.text.toString(),
                name.toString(),
                record_date.toString(),
                record_location.toString(),
                master_record.toString().toInt()
            )
            db.updateItem(item)
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }

    return rowView

}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return stitem[position]
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return stitem[position].id!!.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return stitem.size
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call  [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your `adapter` object when you refresh data. You need to do following changes to make use of it,

**MainActivity**

```
class Detail : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal lateinit var db: DataBaseHelper
    internal var seItem: MutableList<Item_Detail> = ArrayList<Item_Detail>()
    internal lateinit var adapter : Adapter_detail

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

        db = DataBaseHelper(this)
        detail_date.text = rowview_date.toString()
        detail_location.text = rowview_location.toString()
        adapter = Adapter_detail(this, seItem,this)
        list_detail.adapter=adapter
        getDetail()
    }

    private fun getDetail() {
        adapter.refresh(db.Detail)
    }

}
```

**Adapterclass**

```
class Adapter_detail(
    internal var activity: Activity,
    internal var stitem: MutableList<Item_Detail>,
    val context:Context

    ) : BaseAdapter() {

    ...

    fun refresh(newList: List<Item_Detail>) {
         stitem.clear()
         stitem.addAll(newList)
         notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

> **N.B.** I wrote this solution using mobile so please excuse any syntax error.
>   **Let me know if it works?**

P.S. There is a better adapter implementation i.e. `CursorAdapter` which is especially designed for using with database cursor. You can follow this [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) to integrate it.

> Update

I forgot one thing, you need to call `refresh()` inside your `ClickListener` callback in `getView()` function where you perform the update operation. So, it will look like as follows,

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    ...

        btn_edt.setOnClickListener {
            val item= ...
            db.updateItem(item)
            dialog.dismiss()
            refresh(db.Detail)
        }
    }

    return rowView
}
```

Comment: What a splendid code. I really appreciate your help. I edited your code just a little bit to be perfect, from List<Item_Detail> to MutableList<Item> .

Comment: I am glad to help. Happy coding :)